# Change the colour of the particular element in Treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `Treeview` in my `WPF` application. On the fly, in run time, If the element of the `Tree` meets certain condition, It should change its `Font color` from Black To Red.!

`XAML`

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="treeView1" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="LightGray">

    <TreeViewItem Header="Head Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding MainComps}">
        <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RED" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>                                 
        </Style>
    </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeViewItem.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type TextBlock}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Head Tree" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainCompViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Maincompname}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FeatureViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FeatureName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CompViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Component}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>                               
    </TreeViewItem.Resources>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if(selected Item meets certain condition)
    {
         //Change color of tree node
    }
}
```

How can I change the color of particular Node and leave it in the same color SO that when expanded again It should be in `RED`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you can achieve this with bindings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982150/wpf-binding-set-listbox-item-text-color-based-on-property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a boolean property in the model which is true when the elements meets the condition. Then you bind the Foreground like so:

```
                       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolProp}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolProp}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

or with converter:

```
                       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=BoolProp, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=TheKey}}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Instead of particular element all child below the selected node becomes red.

Comment: @BinaryMee How did you solve the issue of all children becoming red?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the Foreground:

```
TreeViewItem ti = (TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem;
ti.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: AM Getting this error. 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedNode' and no extension method 'SelectedNode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think its `SelectedItem`, not `SelectedNode`.

Comment: Yes, SelectedItem seems to be the way to go in WPF (was using forms). But that returns an Object. Try something like: 
TreeViewItem ti =(TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem;
ti.Foreground = Color.Red;

Comment: Edited again, hope it helps: try Brushes.Red instead of Color.Red.

Answer (score 0):

That is embedded into the template. You can only change the color by copying the default `Aero-Style` for the control and changing the hard-coded value.

Or by drilling down the visual tree on-load to change it that way.

To get the default style & tenmplate go through this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Can also check step wise [EXAMPLE](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/06/29/styling-a-treeview-in-silverlight-and-blend-3.aspx) from here.