# WPF binding: Set Listbox Item text color based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm sure this is probably something basic in WPF but I'm new to XAML syntax I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

### The Setup

I have a `LogItem` Type -- just a POCO:

```
public class LogItem
{ 
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public Color MessageColor {get;set;}
}
```

and a List of `LogItem` in my ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<LogItem> _logItems; 
    public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems
    {
        get { return _logItems; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _logItems)
            {
                _logItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LogItems");
            }
        }
    }
```

My viewmodel is bound to the view so that I can do the following:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}">
```

(Obviously I still have to set the display text binding, etc.)

### The Question

Given that I have a `Message` and `MessageColor` property in LogItems, what is the correct XAML syntax to bind the color of the item text to the color I specify?

Comment: Don't forget to make the LogItem properties public. Binding to them won't work otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I actually do but was writing this from memory. Thanks for the catch! I'll edit.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{Binding MessageColor}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

TextBlock `Foreground` expects a `Brush` not a `Color`. Like a lot of things in WPF, There are lot's of ways to approch this. Here is a couple:

1. Change to `MessageColor` property in your viewModel to `Brush`

   ```
   Brush MessageColor {get;set;}
   ```
2. Create a `SolidColorBrush` and bind it to your color

   ```
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}">
         <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MessageColor}"/>
         </TextBlock.Foreground>
     </TextBlock>
   ```
3. Create a `ColorToBrushConverter`

   ```
   public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
   {
         #region IValueConverter Members

         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
                if (value == null) return Brushes.Black; // Default color

                Color color = (Color)value;

                return new SolidColorBrush(color);
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
         }

         #endregion
   }
   ```

In xaml, create the converter as static resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="colorToBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

use it in the binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{Binding MessageColor, Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}"/>
```

Good luck

Comment: MessageColor is a Color, not a Brush.. <TextBlock.Foreground><SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MessageColor}"/></TextBlock.Foreground>

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response! I've no problem changing it to a brush. Unfortunately I won't be near the code for a little bit, so I'll mark this as answered this afternoon. Thanks for giving me insight into the ItemTemplate and DataTemplate stucture! Can't wait until I come up for air and get some time to dig into this bindings in-depth.

Comment: @SeanKilleen I've update my answer to include the converter method too. since your'e in the learning phase It's good to get to familiarize yourself with as many methods as you can. have fun :)

Comment: @Omribitan Instead of adding a ColorToBrushConverter you may just create a SolidColorBrush with a bound Color property in XAML as franssu has shown. That's a lot simpler.

Comment: @Clemens I added that too. This is WPF. you can probably find about 10 ways to this. Just thought of posting couple of options as Sean Killeen said he's new to all this, and I think it's good to know your options. Once you do, off course it's always better to do it the simpler way :)