# Databinding ObservableCollection to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have been trying to figure out the proper way to bind an ObservableCollection of a class to a ListBox with a TextBox DataTemplate. I've tried to implement the code in [WPF binding: Set Listbox Item text color based on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982150/wpf-binding-set-listbox-item-text-color-based-on-property) but that hasn't gotten me very far as of yet. I'm new to WPF DataBinding, having at most programatically set the ItemsSource in simple cases.

I have this class

```
public class item
{
    public string guid;
    public bool found;
    public bool newItem;
    public Brush color;
}
```

and the following ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<item> _items;

public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _items = new ObservableCollection<item>();
}
```

Elsewhere in the code I add items to the collection via

```
_items.Add(new item() { guid = sdr.GetString(0), found = false, newItem = false, color = Brushes.Red });
```

Here's simplified XAML for the ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Items">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text=GUID_HERE Foreground=COLOR_HERE/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've tried several different ways to get this to work properly, yet for none of them the ListBox is updating. Is anyone able to help point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

Your item class needs to use public properties:

```
public class item
{
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public bool found { get; set; }
    public bool newItem { get; set; }
    public Brush color { get; set; }
}
```

You need to set the `ItemsSource` to the collection, and set the current `DataContext`

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    _items = new ObservableCollection<item>();
    ListBox_Items.ItemsSource = _items;     
}
```

You need to update your `DataTemplate` to use the property names of your POCO

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Items">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding guid}" Foreground="{Binding color}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been missing the DataContext = this; as well as explicitly defining the get and set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to bind your ListBox to collection itself.

Your XAML should look like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Items" ItemsSource="{Binding _items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text=GUID_HERE Foreground=COLOR_HERE/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And if you want to change properties of items in your collection (and that changes to appear on UI) you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged (see more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)) interface in "item" class.

Comment: I've done multiple different forms of that. I left it out as I'm not sure what exactly goes there. I've tried simply what you have there using {binding _items} and {binding guid}, {binding color} but to no avail