# Change ListBox Item Background color programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a real hard time understanding how XAML works in connection to C#.
My Problem is, that I have two different `List<String>` Objects filled with Content, I want one `List<String>` to have the backgroundcolor 'blue' and the other one to have the background color 'red'. Afterwards I want to display it in my `ListBox`

My XAML ListBox code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="81,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" BorderBrush="#FF6C6C6C" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListBoxSelectionChanged">

</ListBox>
```

My C# Code that loads all the Content into the ListBox

```
public void AddItemsToListBox()
{
     foreach (var object1 in objects1)
     {
         //I want these Objects to be blue
         listBox1.Items.Add(object1.label);
     }
     foreach (var object2 in objects2)
     {
          //I want these Objects to be red
          listBox1.Items.Add(object2.label);
     }
 }
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982258/1997232). In WPF you have to use binding, doing it `Items.Add()`-way is obsolete. And that `Thread.Sleep(1)` stinks. You can use `async/await` with `await Task.Delay()` to avoid stalling UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
foreach (var object1 in objects1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = object1.label, Background = Brushes.Blue });
 }
 foreach (var object2 in objects2)
 {
     Thread.Sleep(1);
     ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = objects2.label, Background = Brushes.Red });
     //I want these Objects to be red
 }
```

A better way would be to use data binding, styles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

need 50 reputation to comment so added as an answer

why cant you just do it in xaml?

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Background="Red">

</ListBox>
```

just add the background property, this will colour your list boxes

but if you want to become better at wpf i suggest learning DATABINDING so you dont need to manually add objects to the list box

and then after that take a look at MVVM

Comment: I cant do this, because I have two different lists in the same ListBox, but I want each list to have a different color

Comment: ahh i see, can you alter the line where it says:

 ListBox2.Items.Add(objects2.label);

it made me believe you had 2 list boxes