# Change color of Listbox Item based on condition

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to change the color of the line in a listbox based on a condition. The listbox is displaying a list object which is the name and then it calculates the age of the person for a future date.

I am trying to set the color of the line if they are younger then 5 or if they are between 6 and 18.

```
DateTime futureDate = dateTimePicker3.Value;

        foreach (ChildDetails c in children)
        {
            int Age = futureDate.Year - c.DOB.Year;

            if (c.DOB > futureDate.AddYears(-Age))
            {
                Age--;
            }

            if (Age <= 5)
            {
                this.listBox4.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (Age >= 6 && Age <= 18)
            {
                this.listBox4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

            listBox4.Items.Add($" {c.name} {Age}");            
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Add tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `ListView` instead, you can specify the `Forecolor` (and / or `Backcolor`) of each item.  For example, drop a `ListView` on your form and try this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.List;
    var items = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"Shaggy", 4},
        {"Fred", 6},
        {"Daphne", 10},
        {"Velma", 16},
        {"Scooby", 20},
    };

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        int age = item.Value;
        Color foreColor;
        Color backColor;

        if (age <= 5)
        {
            foreColor = Color.Yellow;
            backColor = Color.Purple;
        }
        else if (age >= 6 && age <= 18)
        {
            foreColor = Color.Green;
            backColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        }
        else
        {
            foreColor = Color.Red;
            backColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem
        {Text = item.Key, ForeColor = foreColor, BackColor = backColor});
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: You see reason i'm using a list box cause i select stuff from it that open up in another tab. But i did use your code where i did not need a listbox and used a listview and worked great thank you

Answer (score -1):

just create a listboxItem and change the foreground or background color of that listBoXItem and then insert it in to listbox. [here is a link that can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634835/change-listbox-item-background-color-programmatically)